# scandir error with quote inside $field->original_value

Tags: entities

Can you explain why in my `views-view-field--path-1.tpl.php` this code:

```
$dir="sites/default/files/calibre_server/".$field->original_value;
$files=array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.',''));
```

give me :

> Warning: scandir(sites/default/files/calibre_server/Patten, Lewis
>   B_/Pour l'amour de Kate (1747)): failed to open dir: No such file or
>   directory in include() (line 55 of
>   /volume1/web/drupal/sites/all/modules/calibre_server/themes/views-view-field--path-1.tpl.php).
>   Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in include()
>   (line 55 of
>   /volume1/web/drupal/sites/all/modules/calibre_server/themes/views-view-field--path-1.tpl.php).
>   Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in include() (line
>   55 of
>   /volume1/web/drupal/sites/all/modules/calibre_server/themes/views-view-field--path-1.tpl.php).

But

```
$dir="sites/default/files/calibre_server/Patten, Lewis B_/Pour l'amour de Kate (1747)";
$files=array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.',''));
```

give NO ERROR/WARNING

it's like `$field->original_value` wasn't a string

Comment: The second error follows from the first. Those strings don't look much different to me. I don't much like the looks of the quotation mark and brackets though. If you run the script on a dir without the punctuation do you get the same error?

Comment: This example show that with the same directory , i have an error in one case and none in the others. The quote it's the only character which make warning. Bracket, dot, blank ...no problem.
All other directory (even more complexe) give no warning.

Obviously my directory exist and has all permissions.
If a made a quick php without drupal, scandir work correctly .
It's "$field->original_value;" all the origin of this mistake .

Comment: For information, i have exactly the same warning with "opendir". So it's like $dir wasn't a real string . I tried to use (string) to explicitly force the string type, but result it's always the same. (hidden characters ?)

Comment: It sounds like the quote is the problem. Quotes can get mangled when run through the db, as they need to be sanitized and escaped. There may have been some kind of char replacement (apostrophe, left single quote, right single quote, back tick etc can be problematic). Have you tried addslashes with a second param? Maybe escaping the quote will help. Your markup may also contain a html entity which looks fine when rendered in the browser, but in the db string actually contains a special char code. Take a look at your actual db field and see what's in there, as well as html source.

Comment: I already tried all that things .....
 //$dir=addslashes($dir); 
 //$dir=stripslashes("$dir");  
 //$dir = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $dir);
 //$dir=utf8_encode($dir);
  //$dir=str_replace(" ","\ ",$dir);
  //$dir=stripslashes($dir);
  //$dir=htmlspecialchars($dir);  
 //$dir=htmlentities($dir, ENT_QUOTES); 
 //$dir=htmlspecialchars($dir); 
 //$dir=str_replace("'","\'", $dir);

Comment: This has got me stumped. If I look at the source of your original error, it's got a line feed in it. Is that stack overflow formatting or is there actually a \n in the output?

Comment: I tried $dir=$dir.'xxxx'; and i see no  \n in warning log before xxxx
I also tried
  eval( "\$dir = \"$dir\";" );
 and  $dir=str_replace('\n','', $dir);
without anymore success

Warning: scandir(sites/default/files/calibre_server/Delerm, Philippe/La sieste assassinee (14665)xxxx):

Comment: This issue is getting too long and fiddly to debug in the comments here. Documenting it much further wouldn't be of much benefit to others until it gets solved. I can't move this to chat as you don't have enough privileges yet. I also think that we're not really heading into Drupal-specific territory (fs & db debugging), so I'm going to have to leave off here. If you find a solution, please post back as an answer.

Comment: I FOUND SOLUTION
 $dir=html_entity_decode("$dir", ENT_QUOTES);
Thanks a lot for you help